# Could the sum of powers of non-integers result in a whole number?

Tags: summation, power-series

Concretely, is there a $ b \in \mathbb R $ such that
$ \sum_{i \in I \subset \mathbb N} b^i \in \mathbb W$ ?

Comment: What is a 'whole number'? Do you mean an integer $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Yes, for example.

Comment: Well what else does comprise $\mathbb W$ then? This is not a standard notation as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I've seen it as $\mathbb N \cup \{0\}$.

Comment: You probably mean "powers of non-integers"; "non-integer powers" is something different.

Comment: What is the intent of $i\subset \mathbb N$ ? Do you mean that $i\in I\subset\mathbb N$, where $I$ is a proper subset ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust you're right in both comments. updating...

Comment: I've created a different question for finite series and rationals [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720023/when-is-a-finite-sum-of-powers-of-non-integer-a-rational-number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sum extends over all whole numbers, it is well-known that for $|b|<1$,

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty b^i=\frac1{1-b}.$$

Then take

$$b=1-\frac1n.$$

---

For an example with a finite sum, solve

$$b^2+b=n,$$ giving

$$b=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4n}}{2}.$$

Make sure that $1+4n$ isn't a perfect square.

For example,

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt5-1}2\right)^2+\frac{\sqrt5-1}2=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

In case $\mathbb W = \mathbb Z$:

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left( \frac 12 \right)^i \in \mathbb Z$$

Comment: Any finite series?

Comment: i belongs to N so i=0 can't be term 1

Comment: @Nikunj That is just a matter of convention, some people say $0 \in \mathbb N$, some say $0\not\in\mathbb N$. (And you coud just replace $i$ with $i\pm1$ or so...)

Comment: @flawr I didn't know that, In that case it's correct.

Comment: @nightcod3r What do you mean by finite if $i$ iteraties over all of $\mathbb N$?

Comment: @flawr $i \subset \mathbb N$ can also be a finite set.

Comment: If $i \subset \mathbb N$ how do you define $b^i$?