# When is a finite sum of powers of non-integer a rational number?

Tags: summation, power-series, irrational-numbers

Concretely, is there $ b \in \mathbb R, n,k \in \mathbb N $ such that
$ \sum_{i = n}^{n+k} b^i \in \mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: Perhaps you want $b\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Compare with [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720002/could-the-sum-of-powers-of-non-integers-result-in-a-whole-number?lq=1). Here the sum is finite.

Comment: Do you mean $n+k$ ??

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt sorry, what is $b\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$? can't find a definition.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I meant a decreasing series, but it looks like interchangeable.

Comment: @nightcod3r The notation just means that $b$ is a real number, but not a rational number (Otherwise the statement is relatively trivial e.g. $b=0$ would suffice).

Comment: Out of curiosity, @PeterWoolfitt, when you ask "when" in a statement, does a case satisfying the conditions answer the question, or do you search for all the cases? (In my question, I meant the latter.)

Comment: @nightcod3r If the question has "when," then I would search through all cases. In truth, I had forgotten about the question written in the title of your post, and just answered the question in the body of your post. If you are interested in a complete overview of which $b$ work, I would ask "for which $b\in\mathbb{R}$, are there..." instead of "is there $b$.."

Comment: You're right, the body singles out the general question to one case.

Comment: For given $b,n,k$, I guess that there is no much better criterion than explicitly checking that the sum is rational. A more interesting question is with free $n,k$: for a given algebraic number $b$, is there a sum of (contiguous) powers that is rational ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are innumerable solutions.

For example, with

$$b=1.3348511588502\cdots$$
(computed numerically)

$$b^7+b^6+b^5+b^4+b^3=23.$$

---

Actually, the equation

$$b^n+b^{n-1}+\cdots b^{n-k}=m$$ where $m$ is a rational essentially has irrational roots. All such $b$ are algebraic numbers.

---

For convenience, let us assume the powers run from $n$ to $n+k-1$. Then

$$b^n+b^{n+1}+\cdots b^{n+k-1}=b^n\frac{b^k-1}{b-1}=m.$$

This equation has very rarely integer solutions (in the first place, $m$ must be an integer which is the product of an $n$-th perfect power with another factor.)

For rational solutions, let $b=\dfrac rs$,

$$\dfrac{r^n}{s^n}\frac{\dfrac{r^k}{s^k}-1}{\dfrac rs-1}=\frac pq,$$

and $r,s$ must be solutions of the (terrible) Diophantine equation

$$qr^n(r^k-s^k)=p(r-s)s^{n+k-1}.$$

On the other hand, for any given integer or any rational $b$, you can trivially find a $m$ that fits.

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly possible, and you can take $-\phi$ for example (where $\phi$ is the golden ratio).

Since $$\phi^2=\phi+1,$$
we have
$$(-\phi)^2-\phi=1$$

In general, there are many solutions.